# Make image set available only for debug?

Tags: ios, debugging, ios-simulator, assets

I've got a huge image set for testing purposes. I don't want them to be in the release product. How can tune the image set in the assets catalog for this purpose?

PS I'm going to use this image set as a set of frames for video processor on the simulator for unit testing instead of camera. Since there's no camera on the simulator.

Comment: Instead of handling the set of images, you can get those images from your library by using `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary`.

Comment: @Paddy it's not my case. I'm not using the UIImagePickerController. I want to use images directly in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **create a target** for testing:

- go to project navigator (cmd-1 and select the project name). You will see one target named with same name as the project.
- Right-click the target and select "duplicate".
- Double click the copied target to rename to 'proj-name-debug'

Now you can drag the debug-only images into the project. For each one, at the properties pane on the right, remove the checkmark for the main target, leaving it only for debug target.

Next, at the top of the Xcode window you can choose to compile either the main target or the debug target.

**Note:** The problem will be that when you change the main target (e.g. adding new files), it will not be reflected in the debug target. A simple solution would be to delete the debug target and repeat the duplicate-and-enable-checkmarks process.

Other solutions also exist. For example you can add a build phase with a script for deleting the images from the bundle